# How to post a Image using AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

In my app I am using AFNetworking to Parse services. Here I have to post a image to server, so when ever tried to post image I am getting below error message as response.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.xyz.com:8084/TappyokaCmsService/Service.svc"];

NSString *path=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/InsertUserInfo?User_Name=%@&User_Pwd=%@&User_FName=%@&User_LName=%@&User_Mail=%@&User_Phno=%@&User_Address=%@&User_Dob=%@&Ic_No=%@&User_Active=%@&User_Questions=%@&User_Ans=%@&ImageUrl=%@&IsSocial=%@",@"skull",@"skull",@"skull",@"skull",@"skull",@"skull",@"skull",@"skull",@"skull",@"10001",@"skull",@"skull",@"",@"10001"];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];   [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:path parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
[formData appendPartWithFileData:imageToUpload name:@"skull" fileName:@"skull.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
}];

    // You can add then the progressBlock and the completionBlock
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         NSDictionary *jsons = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:nil];
         NSLog(@"response: %@",jsons);

     }
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         if([operation.response statusCode] == 403)
         {
             NSLog(@"Upload Failed");
             return;
         }
         NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);

     }];

    [operation start];
```

And the error message is:

```
Status code: 404, headers {
"Content-Length" = 1245;
"Content-Type" = "text/html";
Date = "Wed, 20 Nov 2013 15:04:17 GMT";
Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
"X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET"
```

Answer (score 0):

**404 Error**

The 404 error is caused by you trying to access something on the web service that is not found by the server, i.e. you're calling the wrong URL.

**Documentation**

There is hopefully some documentation about how you should be interacting with the webservice in order to upload a photo, I have a feeling you're doing it incorrectly (if I'm not mistaken you should be making SOAP requests?).

Comment: @user2230971 I've edited my answer, but I can't say it much more clearly than what I have.